# How to have dbt run with log error FileNotFound to trigger an exit code that isn't 0?

Tags: dbt

We're running `dbt` version 0.16.1. We've set up our data pipeline to run in Airflow, and have a library set up to map each `dbt` model run within it's own bash operator on Airflow.

The `dbt` run command executed is as follows:

```sh
cd /usr/local/airflow/models/[PACKAGE_NAME] && dbt --log-format json run --models [MODEL_NAME]--no-version-check --profiles-dir=/usr/local/airflow/dags/dags-enterprise-model/enterprise_model/include --target=[TARGET] --profile=[PROFILE]
```

Occasionally (likely when two models are being run at the same time), Airflow will show the following message from within the `dbt run` command:

> INFO - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'logs/dbt.log' -> 'logs/dbt.log.1'

This is problematic because the logfiles do not get updated, but the exit code of the task is listed a 0:

> Command exited with return code 0

This causes Airflow to mark the task as a success; however, the log wasn't printed successfully.

My questions:

1. Is there a a way for these errors to be raised as an actual error?
2. Failing that, is there a way to specific a unique log file?

I'm not sure if this is a gap in my understand, a bug within `dbt`'s logging, or maybe both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely sounds like this is the result of invoking dbt multiple times simultaneously, while having it write to the same files. It's not a dbt bug because we don't intend for dbt to be invoked simultaneously; a single invocation can handle concurrent model runs via threads. Log collisions are one risk of reimplementing dbt's model DAG as Airflow DAGs.

Those are both fair questions:

1. Historically, dbt only used two log levels: `debug` and `info`. See the comment on a related issue: [dbt#2680](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/2680#issuecomment-668258044). I totally appreciate that Airflow and other orchestration tools have well defined notification behaviors when presented with different log levels. A community member actually *just* opened a PR to add error-level logging ([dbt#2723](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/pull/2723)).
2. It is possible to set a custom log path for a dbt invocation using the `log-path` config in `dbt_project.yml` ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/log-path/))

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Yes, I guess I don't think of the "multiple dbt runs" piece of this as an error; I would suggest that the `dbt` shell exit status IS closer to a bug -- is there a purpose for a status of 0 when the run has errors within it?

I'm not sure that we would need this workaround if we could execute an API call as a post-hook ;)

Comment: That's fair enough. If you're on Snowflake, you could take a look at [external functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions.html)...

Comment: Sadly, we're running on Netezza, and we don't have a clear roadmap to move to the cloud just yet (probably a few years off). Again, thanks for your response. We love dbt (we moved our most central analytics project to use dbt in production a bit more than a month ago, and we love it!